# In Perl, why am I getting "uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)" when I try to check if a variable matches two patterns?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get a sequence starting with ATG and stopping with TAG, TAA or TGA out of a text file.

I get the error message

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at line 12

and it counts every line not only the ones I want.

I think there is something wrong with how I use the regular expressions but I don't know how.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test  = "Bin.txt";
my $count = "0"; 

sub ORF {
    my ($file) = @_; # reading file in 

    open ( my $FH, "<", $file ) or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    while ( my $line = <$FH> ) { #reading each line of file

        if ( $line = ( ( ~/^ATG/ ) and ( ~/TAG$|TAA$|TGA$/ ) ) ) { # looking for sequence with ATG at the beginning and TAG,TAA,TGA at the end 
            $count = $count +1; # counting these sequences 
        }
    }
}

ORF $test; 
print $count;
```

Answer (score 2):

The effect of

```
 $line = (( ~/^ATG/) and (~/TAG$|TAA$|TGA$/))
```

is to assign the result of

```
 (~($_ =~ /^ATG/) and ~($_ =~ /TAG$|TAA$|TGA$/))
```

to `$line`.

`=~` is a single operator. `=` and `~` on their own mean different things. `=~` cannot be split like that.

What you need to write is:

```
 ($line =~/^ATG/) and ($line =~ /TAG$|TAA$|TGA$/)
```

I actually recommend you keep the two simple regex matches corresponding to "`$line` begins with `ATG` and ends with one of `TAG`, `TAA`, or `TGA`", instead of trying to combine both conditions into a single pattern and making it less readable.

Further advice:

- Don't write `my $count = "0";`. This is actually a FAQ: [What is wrong with always quoting "$vars"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What%27s-wrong-with-always-quoting-%22%24vars%22%3f): "*The problem is that those double-quotes force stringification--coercing numbers and references into strings--even when you don't want them to be strings.*" In this case, you should initialize it with `0`.
- Instead of `$count = $count +1`, use `++ $count`.
- Instead of having a global `$count`, return the count from the subroutine.
- Even though lexical filehandles are automatically closed when exiting the scope, it is still better to explicitly close them when they are no longer needed.
- Don't omit parentheses from subroutine invocations. That is, instead of `ORF $test`, always write `ORF($test)`, especially since all uppercase bareword names tend to be reserved for either package level file handles or constants.

So, I would rewrite your code as (untested because I do not have the data):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

run( @ARGV );

sub run {
    my $file = shift;
    print ORF($file), "\n";
    return;
}

sub ORF {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "Can't open '$file': $!";

    my $count = 0;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        if ( ($line =~ /^ATG/) and ($line ~= /(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)$/)) {
            ++ $count;
        }
    }
    close $fh
        or die "Failed to close '$file': $!";

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful (and makes a lot of sense).

Comment: *'What is wrong with always quoting "$vars"'* is about, well, putting double quotes around variables, not around numeric constants, which is a much lesser sin. And thank you for using the appropriate pre-increment operator instead of the ubiquitous post-increment

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing the `~` operator. It's bitwise negation and has nothing to do with regexes. The one you probably meant is `=~` but it can't be split. Therefore the conditional operator should look

```
if ($line =~ /^ATG/ and $line =~ /TAG$|TAA$|TGA$/)
```

But this can be described in a single regex:

```
if ($line =~ /^ATG.*(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)$/))
```